# Displaying Colour and Size attributes in Magento product page

Tags: magento

I have a working code

```
$cModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$cModel->load($_product->getId());

echo '<p>Product name :',$cModel->getData('name'),'</p>';
echo '<p>Manufacturer id :',$cModel->getData('manufacturer'),'</p>';

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
        ->setEntityTypeFilter($_product->getResource()->getTypeId())

        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_code', 'manufacturer');
$attribute = $attributes->getFirstItem()->setEntity($_product->getResource());

echo '<p> Manufacturer :',$attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($cModel->getData('manufacturer')),'</p>';
```

It is working with Manufacturer. But not working with Size and Colour Attributes. Thank You.

Comment: Two questions: What type of product attributes are they? (text, drop-down, etc) Also, could you post the code in which you try to get the values for the size and colour attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Under Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes you must make sure that the attributes mentioned have their value set to "Yes" for the option "Used in Product Listing".

Comment: I have already set Used in Product Listing to "Yes". But no  use.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `<?php echo $_product->getAttributeText("color"); ?>` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Drop Downs** for Attributes add the below code in your **/template/catalog/product/view.phtml** file

This will display your **First Attribute**

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

This will display your **Second Attribute** (More than 1 Custom Attribute)

```
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
<?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
<?php endif;?>
```